# Negating a non-math statement

Tags: logic

The statement that I have to negate is: Every math student likes mental health an memorizing formulas. 
I think the negation is: There exists a math student who does not like mental math or memorizing formulas.
But I also think it might just to be: There exists a math student who likes mental math and memorizing formulas.
I’m not sure if I’m thinking too much into the statement because I understand a negation is not P, but I’m overthinking. If anyone can offer some advice I’d really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: The former is the correct negation

Comment: Since English semantics is not always precise, your first one could mean "dislikes both mental math and memorizing" or "dislikes at least one of mental math and memorizing." Which one do you mean? Personally, I would pick the one you mean and phrase your sentence unambiguously, even if it takes a few more words to do so -- but that's just my opinion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not think too much. Just ask yourself, what would be enough to encourage someone that the statement is not true.

And, it turns out that the first your guess is right. There could exist a student who does not like mental health **or** memorizing formulas.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very encouraging. I feel like I’ve been starring at these negations for too long that I don’t remember the proper way of negating. I’ll stop overthinking lol.

Answer (score 0):

The statement claims that *every* student must have the said property, so saying that there exists atleast one student which does not have it will suffice. Your second statement isn’t doing anything but further increasing the probability of the said claim being true.